# Laravel "envoy run" command not working with ssh key

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravel-envoy

I am  running following command in a laravel project folder and getting following error.

```
rakib$ envoy run list --env=production
[ubuntu@54.187.123.4]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

But I can successfully ssh using following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/sw-new.pem ubuntu@54.187.123.4
```

My ~/.ssh/config file content looks like:

```
Host 54.187.123.4
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sw-new.pem
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the possible reason of getting "Permission denied" error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that envoy is using the wrong user when attempting to ssh into the production server. Specify a user in your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host 54.187.123.4
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sw-new.pem
    User ubuntu
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible as [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24590617/1756032) for **AWS user** when you attempting to ssh in production mode, after define **"config"** file as **"~/.ssh/config"**:

```
Host ec2-52-29-45-15.eu-central-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile /home/tux/Desktop/ssh/masterpro.pem
    User ubuntu
```